# Clicking on synced `Documents` spawns an additional `OneDrive` folder to open

Tags: windows-10, sync, onedrive, my-documents

Every time I click on my Windows 10 `Documents` folder, that specific folder is opened (expected behavior) and an additional `OneDrive` folder is opened (unexpected behavior). How do I disable this annoyance?

Yes; my `Documents` and `OneDrive` are linked to sync to each other. But I don't need two folders to open every time `Documents` is invoked. This tends to be a nuisance, when I'm quickly going in and out of my `Documents` folder. It keeps throwing an additional `OneDrive` Windows Explorer instance in front of me, and I have to keep "X" closing it.

Thanks for any help.